# URL with domain substitution in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, multilingual

We have a website, www.domain.com, which we want to also publish in other languages like fr.domain.com, jp.domain.com, etc. Each language subdomain will be a separately managed site, it is not a true multi-lingual system. But we want to be able to have a common chunk of code on the top which can link between the same page on different language domains.

Specifically, I'd like to have a link of language links along the top like this:
    French | Japanese

Now, suppose the user is on the english site on a page www.domain.com/a/b/c.html

I would like the language links on top to be automatically written as

```
<a href='http://fr.domain.com/a/b/c.html'>French</a>|
<a href='http://jp.domain.com/a/b/c.html'>Japanes</a>|
...etc...
```

This is easy using server-side techniques but I need it to be something that can be done purely with HTML and/or Javascript (i.e., a little chunk of HTML and/or Javascript which can be inserted via the richtext editor of a content management system).

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: I don't understand where you are having issues. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the current location

```
document.location.href
```

Inject the correct language

```
function makeLink(lang) {
    return document.location.href.replace(document.location.hostname, lang + "." + document.location.hostname)
}

...

var fr_link = makeLink("fr"); // French link
```

Use that string for your link.

JS Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/CvBK4/

This is more than enough for you to work out the rest.

Answer (score 1):

when i get it correctly, you want to alter the href of links on a page to the same location but different host in url.

i would do that like this in javascript

```
var lang = 'de'
var list = document.querySelectorAll('a');
for (k in list) {
 if (list[k].href!==undefined) {
  list[k].href = list[k].href.replace(/^(http[s]?:\/\/)([^.]*)(.*)$/,'$1'+lang+'$3');
 }
}
```

Comment: Useful to know, but I did not want to replace every link on the page. Thank you nevertheless!